# React Highmaps going from one to 2nd or 2nd to third chart

Tags: node.js, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

i am using highmap in reactjs where i want to go from 2nd chart to 3rd chart like:-> world->US Country -> US states. My code is here :https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-bush-rt8ob?file=/src/App.js
Can you help me out from this.

Comment: Hi @Shubham Oryxn, Could you tell me more about the problem? Do you want to use a drilldown feature to change the map?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, I am easily go to one map to 2nd map using drilldown but when i click in second map than i am failed to create new map

Comment: First of all, you should disable updating chart by the wrapper, so set `allowChartUpdate` to `false`: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-fire-4b80v?file=/src/App.js Next, your script loads onle US map, you need to load the correct one.